# Django: Can't load cyrillic font in font-face

Tags: css, django, fonts, font-face

I'm using `django-easy-pdf` to create pdf reports. So, I need my font to be cyrillic . In my template I write:

```
@font-face { font-family: Arimo-Regular; src: url('{% static 'static/themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf' %}'); }

html {
    font-family: Arimo-Regular, Arial, 'sans-serif';
    color: #333333;
}
```

But all the time, the font is `sans-serif`. I found some cyrillic font: `Arimo-Regular`, but it's not working. Maybe this font is not supported by browser? I've tried several cyrylic fonts, but it remains `sans-serifs`
And i'm not sure whether that font is loaded or not, but `{% static 'static/themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf' %}`, because I do so with my `css` in `main.html` and it works.
My project structure:
[image]

As you can see, those squares are cyrilic symbols, and `NETWORK` doesn't show any errors:[image]

And my whole `report.html`:

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block extra_style %}
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: "Arimo-Regular"; src: url({% static 'themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf' %}); }
        {% comment %}@font-face { font-family: FiraMono; src: url('{% static 'static/themes/font/FiraMono-Regular.otf' %}'); }
        @font-face { font-family: "Lato Light"; src:  url('{% static 'static/themes/font/FiraMono-Regular.otf' %}')};{% endcomment %}

        html {
            font-family: "Arimo-Regular", Arial, 'sans-serif';
            color: #333333;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0 0 6px 0;
            font-size: 11pt;
            font-family: "Arimo-Regular", Arial, 'sans-serif';
        }

        table {
            line-height: 140%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
            table.bordered {
                border-top: 0.1pt solid #999999;
                border-bottom: 0.1pt solid #999999;
            }

            tr, td, th { border: none; }

            th {
                font-size: 8pt;
                border-bottom: 0.1pt solid #999999;
                padding: 3px 0;
                line-height: 1;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: "Arimo-Regular", Arial, 'sans-serif';
            }

            td {
                font-size: 8pt;
                font-family: "Arimo-Regular", Arial, 'sans-serif';
                vertical-align: top;
                padding: 3px 0;
            }

            td:last-child { padding-bottom: 0; }

        .text-left { text-align: left; }
        .text-right { text-align: right; }
        .bottom-10 { margin-bottom: 10px; }
        .bottom-20 { margin-bottom: 20px; }

        .header { color: #7f7f7f; }
        .header p { font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.5em; }
        .header-link { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #4F81BD; font-size: 14px; }
        .logo { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: -25px; }
        .logo img { zoom: 60%; }

        .recipient { margin-left: 7cm; }

        .main h1 {
            margin: 18px 0 18px 0;
            font-size: 250%;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #4F81BD;
        }

        .main h2 {
            margin: 18px 0 6px 0;
            font-size: 180%;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .info { border: 1px solid #4F81BD; padding: 10px; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; }
        .info a { color: #4F81BD; text-decoration: none; }

    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        <div class="recipient bottom-10">
            <p class="bottom-10">
                <strong>ACME Inc.</strong>
                <br> John Doe
            </p>
            <p class="bottom-10">
                Street Name <br>
                Postal Code <br/>
                City
            </p>
            <p>{{ today|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT" }} UTC</p>
        </div>


        <p class="info">
            This is an example of <a href="https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf">django-easy-pdf</a>
            &ndash; Django PDF rendering the easy way.
            Check <a href="http://en.ig.ma/">en.ig.ma</a> for Django and Python development.
        </p>

        <div class="main">
            <h1>Sample Invoice</h1>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left" style="font-family: Arimo-Regular;">кирилица</th>
                        <th class="text-right">PackAmount</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price per bottle</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price per package</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price per package</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for item in order.orderproduct_set.all %}
                    <tr>

                        <td class="text-left">{{ item.product.brand.name }} {{ item.product.volume }}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{ item.product_amount }}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{ item.product.price }}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{ item.product.package.price }}</td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="bottom-20">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-right"><strong>100 Doge</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <h2>Payment details</h2>

            <p class="bottom-20">
                Please cover the invoice within 10 days.
            </p>

            <p>Dogecoin address (it's real): <strong>DREWeqR5KB2rbpJFybKvWepNs6sUQZowNs</strong></p>
            <pdf:barcode value="DREWeqR5KB2rbpJFybKvWepNs6sUQZowNs" type="qr" barwidth="100" barheight="100" />
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Rendered html:
[image]

Comment: You can check if the font is loaded via the dev-tools in your browser. In Chrome: `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open the dev tools. Go in the **Network** tab and refresh. If it is not loaded it should appear in red. You can also check the url requested by your browser by hovering, to see if it corresponds to what you intended.

Comment: Id doesn't appear in red, but this way is not working, because I try to load unexisted font, but nothing appears in red

Comment: When you say that you wrote the above css in your template you're talking about your html file in `<style></style>` tags, and not your css file, right? Because if it is in your css file then you can't use `{% static '' %}` and you have to specify a relative path from your css to your font file.

Comment: My font-face is in report.html file

Comment: Do you really have a `static` directory within a `static` directory? If not... `{% static 'themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf' %}`

Comment: @mevius, `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('static', os.path.abspath('static')),
)`

Comment: @Mathieu David, I tried to place my font in `font` folder in the same directory where `report.html` is, but the font hasn't changed:`@font-face { font-family: Arimo-Regular; src: url(font/Arimo-Regular.ttf); }`

Comment: Please provide the **absolute path** to your font file. It needs to be within the `static` directory, not in the template directory.

Comment: @mevius, if my template is located in `manager/templates/report.html', so how absolute path is gonna look like? I provided my project structure above in post. I tried this, but not working: `url('../static/themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf')`

Comment: could you show us what the rendered html looks like via your browser dev-tools ? (the part that is causing trouble)

Comment: @Mathieu David, updated post. It can't find my cyrillic font, so it takes `sans-serif`

Comment: I'm sorry I meant the "rendered" `<style></style>` tags, could you show that ? :)

Comment: @Mathieu David, as I understand, all rendered styles are built-in html tags. Maybe this is the way `django-easy-pdf` works. example of some div: `<div data-canvas-width="91.88000000000001" style="left: 225.714px; top: 602.059px; font-size: 13.3333px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.09381);">PricePerBottle</div>`

Comment: But in `<head>` of your source you should still have `<style>` tags. What is the content of those ?

Comment: @Mathieu David, found similiar issue, but they just add new cyrillic font and it works, not my case :( https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/issues/12

Comment: @Mathieu David, in `<head>` there is only  one link except for `<script>`s:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="viewer.css">`... no styles... maybe it's because it's not simple html page, it's pdf document

Comment: And if you dont use `{% static '...' %}`? `@font-face { font-family: "Arimo-Regular"; src: url(static/themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf); }` ? Does that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78197/discussion-between-andrew-and-mathieu-david).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is number 2 place in Google for this question (after an issue in `django-easy-pdf`), here's a solution.

This is [the code that supplies the font files](https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/blob/360f75cf5258558370538a4ba20c4dbe7c91e418/easy_pdf/rendering.py#L23-L46):

```
if settings.STATIC_URL and uri.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL):
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
elif settings.MEDIA_URL and uri.startswith(settings.MEDIA_URL):
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
else:
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri)
```

So, your font must be either in STATIC_ROOT or MEDIA_ROOT on the server's filesystem. Which means:

1) Add the font to static files of your project (assuming your static files are set up properly).

2) **Important:** run `python manage.py collectstatic`, so the file is actually copied there, *even if you run the development server*.

3) If you:

- placed your font into `static/fonts/awesomefont.ttf` of your project
- your `STATIC_URL` is, say `/static_files/`

Then you can use either of those:

```
/* Relative to static files' root */
@font-face { font-family: Awesome; src: url(fonts/awesomefont.ttf); }
/* Full static URL */
@font-face { font-family: Awesome; src: url(/static_files/fonts/awesomefont.ttf); }
```

Again, please note - the font will be loaded by `xhtml2pdf` utility, not the browser, so those files must be local to the machine Django is running on.