# 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable django-easy-pdf

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf, django-staticfiles

I use django-easy-pdf library for my project. When I try to set custom cyrillic font I have

> TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable

I`ve seen where the error appear and here is what I got

[image: Error debug]

Looks like I have a problem with **src url**, but I have no idea how to solve this issue. I`ve tried change *src: url()* different ways (manual input,{% static 'path' %}, etc) , but it is not working. I really stuck.

Django = 1.10, Python = 3.4.3

Here`s my template.

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block extra_style %}
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: Palatino Linotype; src: url({% static 'automobiles/fonts/bold.ttf' %});
    }
    body{
        font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #333333;
    }
    </style>
{% endblock extra_style %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>PYTHON3 RULES</h1>
        <p>Это должно работать</p>
        <h3>Но библиотеке что-то не нравится</h3>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

*Project structure:*

[image: Project structure]

*settings.py*

[image: setting.py]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323242/django-cant-load-cyrillic-font-in-font-face 
I\`ve seen this topic, but it didn`t help me. Maybe I do it something wrong

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT should be os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'). I am assuming automobiles is the main project.

Comment: no, autodb is the main project, automobiles it is the app. I refresh picture about project

Comment: your /static/ is set to path staticfiles dir, but your bold.ttf is in static directory.

Comment: Staticfiles dir it is folder which generate after command (python manage.py collectstatic). So I have fonts in both folder. I try this)